# Is there way to make PDF files from its XML source in ColdFusion?

Tags: xml, pdf, coldfusion, lifecycle, cfpdfform

I need to make some changes to XML source of a PDF file, and save the result as a PDF in ColdFusion. The first part is easy. I do not know how to convert the XML to PDF just like how LifeCycle does!

The XML source is exactly the same content that you can see in LifeCycle if you click on XML source (for dynamic pdf files of course).

Thx

btw, I know that I can read the actual PDF using CFPDFFORM and populate it with XML data, the problem is , cfpdfform truncates the  tag for some reason, so I cant use it.

Comment: The ColdFusion equivalent of dealing with PDFs using XML like LiveCycle does is DDX.  I have some blog posts that might help: http://www.carolinamantis.com/wordpress/?cat=11

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  You can only use `<cfdocument>` and `<cfpdf>` to manipulate PDF in CF, and neither of them support creating PDF files from "XML source".  The closing thing would be DDX, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with "XML source" that you were referring to.